# Warning message using writeRaster() - not updated for proj >= 6

Tags: raster, r

Using the code below to write a raster to disk:

```r
library('raster')
        
r <- raster(nrow = 5856, ncol = 9141)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
        
writeRaster(r, tempfile(fileext = ".tif"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

always produces a warning message:

```
In .gd_SetProject(object, ...) : NOT UPDATED FOR PROJ >= 6
```

What causes the message and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Update `raster`, `rgdal`, `gdal` and `libproj`. See also https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html, https://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html

Comment: @JRR Sadly that doesn't solve the issue. The warning message remains.

Comment: I don't (no longer) have the message so I guess something is not up to date on your machine. Please show the output of `rgdal::getGDALVersionInfo()`,
`rgdal::getPROJ4VersionInfo()`,
`packageVersion("rgdal")`,
`packageVersion("raster")`

Comment: @JRR GDAL Version: `GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28`,  PROJ4 Version: `Rel. 7.0.0, March 1st, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 700]`, rGDAL Version: `1.5.16` and Raster Version: `3.3.13`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, (In .gd_SetProject(object, ...) : NOT UPDATED FOR PROJ >= 6), did you find any solution for the issue please share your experience?

Comment: @AhmadAnsari Unfortunately not.

Comment: same issue here `In .gd_SetProject(object, ...) : NOT UPDATED FOR PROJ >= 6` with R 4.x and RStudio 1.4.1. No solution. even Failing to reproject using GDALwarp

Comment: Solutions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014085/saving-raster-not-updated-for-proj-6

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a crs to your raster object, **before** saving it?

```
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat"
```